# How do I use runit with zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

How do I use runit with zookeeper?  Its running but I get those nasty logs.....

Here is my run file
    more /etc/sv/zookeeper/run

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
exec  /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh start >> /tmp/zookeeper.log 2>&1
```

below is the tail of my log file
     tail -f zookeeper.log

```
Using config: /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... already running as process 32701.
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... already running as process 32701.
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... already running as process 32701.
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... already running as process 32701.
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... already running as process 32701.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of it, zookeeper is already running in your system. Or there is a lock file which didn't get deleted due to an unclean shutdown. Check using `zkServer.sh status` to see if it is running properly.

Comment: No..its not running when I start zk with runit.  When I start zookeeper with runit the above logs occur.  I guess runit cant manage zk.

Comment: @Tampa What I meant was.. The reason why runit cannot start zookeeper is because it is finding the PID file in the zookeeper directory, which usually means that zookeeper is already running, or it was terminated uncleanly and the PID file was not deleted. To fix: Find if zookeeper is actually running, using `ps aux`. If not, delete the pidfile in the zookeeper directory.